# UL class not working? Only LI works?

Tags: html, css

I just started HTML/CSS two days ago.. Please go easy on me. I'm currently building a website. For some reason, I cannot get the the HTML class/id to render with CSS. To make it work, I have to make a class for each list. How do I make it so that the class for ul as a whole? (When I take out the `<li class="name_here>`, all the styles don't work anymore)

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul class="navi">
        <li class="navi"><a href="http://www.bestfoodservice.us/product"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_07.jpg" width="104" height="67" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.bestfoodservice.us/company"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_09.jpg" width="105" height="67" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.bestfoodservice.us/facility"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_11.jpg" width="110" height="67" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.bestfoodservice.us/careers"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_13.jpg" width="105" height="66" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <ul class="lastbit">
            <li><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_34.jpg" width="85" height="29"/></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_37.jpg" width="62" height="16" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_38.jpg" width="69" height="16" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_39.jpg" width="100" height="16" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="lang">
            <li class="lang"><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_41.jpg" width="29" height="14" /></a></li>
            <li class="lang"><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_43.jpg" width="39" height="17" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social">
            <li class="social"><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_27.jpg" width="30" height="29" /></a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_29.jpg" width="30" height="29" /></a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="http://linkedin.com"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_31.jpg" width="30" height="29" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navi {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
.lastbit {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.lang {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
.social {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: I'm trying to see what I'm doing wrong with the class/ids. As you can see in my HTML, the class/id will work with the CSS if each '<li>' have their class, but when I take out the "<li class=" title_here'> out, it doesn't work with just styling with '<ul class="title_here'>

Comment: @ThomasTung: For future reference its sensible when asking questions to have as little code in your question as possible. That is trim out any unnecessary parts. A lot of the HTML and CSS in the question don't make a difference to your question so including them just muddies your question.

Comment: @Chris, sorry! I didn't know if you guys needed to see the whole code to see if I'm doing something wrong somewhere that is making it not work correctly.

Comment: @Thomas: Its always better to give too much than too little but one very good way to debug is to take out styles to see if they make a difference. If you take it out and it fixes it then you know that that is part of the problem. If it doesn't make a difference you can be fairly sure its irrelevant. Not always foolproof but making a minimal version of your problem can often help yourself work out the cause and if not makes it easier for others to see what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up more on selectors in CSS. In a nutshell what you are doing with this:

```
.social {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

is saying that everything with the class `social` gets the given styles applied to it.

When you have that class on each of the `li` elements it applies as you want. However when you are putting that class on the `ul` it is applying the styles to the `ul` and not the `li`. To fix this you need to specify that you want the styles on the li by changing the selector slightly:

```
.social li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

The above says that all li elements that are descendents of items with class `social` should have the styles which is what you want.

Comment: I found out what was confusing me. I will certainly read up more on CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you might try something like this.

```
.lastbit li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Your markup can then be:

```
<ul class="lastbit">
  <li></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

This will apply the style to all the li elements of the ul you mark with that style.

Answer (score 0):

To style all lists, use:

```
ul{
    /* styles here */
}
```

To style all of the items in the list, use

```
li{
    /* styles here */
}
```

To style all of the anchors in all of the items in the list, use

```
li a{
    /* styles here */
}
```

Also, just so you're aware, your first `ul` has the class name "navi" and so do the items within the list. It also only has one `<li>`, although you likely want 4 (since you have 4 links in it).

Comment: Thanks for all the info and help!